# restart failed task when running ansible-playbook with --step option

Tags: ansible

ansible-playbook provides command line option for step by step play execution. If a task fail during the run then is it possible to rerun same task without re-starting the complete play?

Answer (score 1):

--start-at-task is what you're looking for.

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook --start-at-task="task-name" --step
```

Cheers

Comment: --start-at-task will start execution from given task but it wouldn't restart the execution  with all facts set by previous tasks. we have playbooks which takes hours to complete the setup & if run fails in between then we have to fix & restart the whole play from first task.

Comment: I think what I was looking for is `ANSIBLE_STRATEGY` option. With debug mode this allows rerunning same tasks with changes upon failure. Thanks for reply ..